# "window is not defined" error when using server-side rendering angular

Tags: angular

Here the chunk of code from server .js where am facing this error please help

```
var CompatibilityHelper = /** @class */ (function () {

            function CompatibilityHelper() {
            }
            CompatibilityHelper.isTouchEvent = function (event) {
                if (((window)).TouchEvent !== undefined) {
                    return event instanceof TouchEvent;
                }
                return event.touches !== undefined;
            };
            CompatibilityHelper.isResizeObserverAvailable = function () {
                return ((window)).ResizeObserver !== undefined;
            };
            return CompatibilityHelper;
        }());
```

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>                       at Function.module.exports.CompatibilityHelper.isResizeObserverAvailable
>   (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:236110:9)
>                       at SliderComponent.module.exports.SliderComponent.unsubscribeResizeObserver
>   (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:236698:33)
>                       at SliderComponent.module.exports.SliderComponent.ngOnDestroy
>   (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:236640:14)
>                       at callProviderLifecycles (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:24508:18)
>                       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:24476:13)
>                       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:24466:29)
>                       at destroyView (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:32662:5)
>                       at callViewAction (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:32788:13)
>                       at execComponentViewsAction (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.js:32710:13)
>                       at destroyView (D:\SourceTree\KbProperties(09-11-2019)\KbProperties\Angular\Angular
>   New\ClientAngular\dist\server.
>   js:32661:5)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to resolve your error first before copy-pasting your error here. A simple google search will give you a ton of results.

Comment: You should define `window` as a global first, as it is not already defined!